# How to import external libraries in jshell java 9?

Tags: java-9, jshell

I was trying to understand jshell and fumbled to import external library. As of date I couldn't see any suggestion/solution for this.

Can someone please let me know if already figured this out.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/51572213/3728901

Answer (score 80, accepted):

I tried with `9 Build 162 Linux 64-bit` with preparation:

- Downloaded `guava-19.0.jar` and `commons-lang3-3.4.jar` to
  `/opt/libs`

**The following options are available:**

1. Specify **`CLASSPATH`** environment variable:

   `$> CLASSPATH="/opt/libs/commons-lang3-3.4.jar:/opt/libs/guava-19.0.jar" bin/jshell`
2. Specify classpath with **jshell** option:

   `$> bin/jshell --class-path /opt/libs/guava-19.0.jar:/opt/libs/commons-lang3-3.4.jar`
3. Configure evaluation context within **jshell** session with command `/env`, `/reset` or `/reload`(these commands are different, you can check out with its help info), take `/env` as example:

   `jshell> /env -class-path /opt/libs/commons-lang3-3.4.jar:/opt/libs/guava-19.0.jar`

And then you're able to either `import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils` or `import com.google.common.base.Optional;`.

Comment: Under Windows 7 it works in the same way - set the CLASSPATH environmental variable, which points to the jar file, then use 'import' to import the class/package.

Comment: @Prags I am trying to use option2 and 3 in windows 10 environment with Jshell it is not working do we need to do something else to make it work in Windows10.

Comment: @Beast can you check this, might it help you http://www.java67.com/2012/08/what-is-path-and-classpath-in-java-difference.html

Comment: @Beast JShell on Windows requires either double-backslash paths `\\ ` or forward slash paths `/` separated by semicolon `;` - e.g., `/env --class-path c:/path/to/jars/file.jar;c:\\another\\path\\to\\jars\\file.jar`

Comment: For me, on windows, I have to omit `/env`, just `--class-path c:/path...`

Answer (score 14):

- You can load **maven artifacts** into JShell through [this (modified) version of JShell](https://github.com/bhagatsingh/try-artifact).
- It also supports **/cls** command to **clear JShell Console**. See Maven Example below.

[image]

Give a try and share your feedback.

Comment: "/resolve" is not available in the Java 9 release version of JShell

Comment: yes /resolve and /cls are not there in Java 9. We have added them in our JShell version.

Answer (score 13):

Easier way in maven, see [In JShell, how to import classpath from a Maven project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47705036/in-jshell-how-to-import-classpath-from-a-maven-project): In your project directory, run:

```
mvn com.github.johnpoth:jshell-maven-plugin:1.0:run
```

---

If you have a maven `pom.xml`, you can use https://github.com/bitterfox/jshell-maven-plugin. This uses all dependencies as the classpath. The plugin is not currently in maven, so you need to clone the repo: `git clone https://github.com/bitterfox/jshell-maven-plugin.git`. [Then](https://github.com/bitterfox/jshell-maven-plugin),

1. `mvn clean install`
2. add the following to your `pom.xml`:

   ```
   <build>
   <plugins>
       <plugin>
           <groupId>net.java.openjdk.shinyafox</groupId>
           <artifactId>jshell-maven-plugin</artifactId>
           <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
       </plugin>
   </plugins>
   </build>
   ```
3. start with `mvn jshell:compile`

Answer (score 9):

Start Jshell importing all jars from a directory

Let directory is `~/app/java/jars/`

```
jshell --class-path $(ls -d ~/app/java/jars/* | tr '\n' ':')
```

Answer (score 3):

You can load external library with the command:

```
/env --class-path /path/to/jar/file
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Fish shell, you can set the alias in your fish config file. Here's how you can do it. In your fish config ( **~/.config/fish/config.fish** ), add

```
alias jshell "~/.jenv/versions/12.0.1/bin/jshell --class-path (find ~/.m2/repository/ -name \"*.jar\" | tr '\n' ':')"
```

This will load all the jars in your class path.

Note: Change the jshell path and jars repository path accordingly.

Comment: it has some scripting error but this will work - `jshell --class-path $(find ~/.m2/repository/ -name "*.jar" | tr '\n' ':')` make sure you don't have too many jars otherwise you will get `bash: /usr/bin/jshell: Argument list too long`

Answer (score 0):

If you use script like (find  -name "*.jar" | tr '\n' ':') to concat, then you alias will be huge string which I don't like.

If you want to include a directory with all jars, the trick is to use colon (:) first and then the directory name as below -

```
alias java-shell="~/jdk-10.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/jshell --class-path :<dir-name>/jars/* "
```

Otherwise it won't work properly. I wish they should have make it cleaner.