# In JShell, how to import classpath from a Maven project

Tags: maven, classpath, java-9, jshell

I have a local Maven project under development. How can I launch `jshell` with the project class path with all the dependencies, so that I can test project or dependency classes inside JShell.

Comment: This seems to be a useful use case that is not clearly addressed by jshell tutorials or elsewhere online.

Comment: What about using exec-maven-plugin?

Comment: Are you looking for a command line only solution? Here is an IDE-specific solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48143960/how-to-import-a-custom-class-in-intellij-jshell-console

Comment: you would probably be better off looking into gradle

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I wrote a simple shell script put in the execution search path:

Shell script file: **mshell** (for *inux)

```
mvn dependency:build-classpath -DincludeTypes=jar -Dmdep.outputFile=.cp.txt
jshell --class-path `cat .cp.txt`:target/classes
```

Shell script file: **mshell** (for Windows cmd.exe)

```
mvn dependency:build-classpath -DincludeTypes=jar -Dmdep.outputFile=.cp.txt
for /F %i in (.cp.txt) do jshell --class-path "%i;target/classes"
```

Then in the maven project directory (for multi-module project, make sure in the module directory instead of parent directory), run:

```
$ cd $MAVEN_PROJECT_HOME   #make sure module folder for multi-module project
$ mshell
```

[gist link](https://gist.github.com/jianwu/9b36a3c9b47edd9c2304ccbf9ace081b)

*Thanks Jay for pointing out -DincludeTypes=jar maven option.*

Comment: if you use mvn dependency:build-classpath -DincludeTypes=jar then it won't include the pom dependencies.

Comment: Happy to upvote if you can create script for Windows as well.

Comment: "Goal requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory" - requires some pom.xml in the current dir to work.

Comment: This is a nice solution, however cmd variables are limited to 8191 characters. So it will not work for a looong classpath.

Comment: @MarcosPirmez In Java9, there's Argument File concept. That could help to solve the cmd line limit problem. Haven't tried that. Feel free to try it and update the answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201816/how-to-set-a-long-java-classpath-in-windows

Answer (score 44):

You can use the jshell-maven-plugin:

```
mvn com.github.johnpoth:jshell-maven-plugin:1.3:run
```

which will fire up a JShell session with your project's runtime path. If you want to include your test dependencies just add -DtestClasspath to the command.

**NOTE:** the plugin expects the project to be built already. If not, invoke the appropriate Maven build phase before the plugin e.g:

```
mvn [install|compile|test-compile] com.github.johnpoth:jshell-maven-plugin:1.3:run
```

Source code: https://github.com/johnpoth/jshell-maven-plugin; contributions are welcome :) full disclaimer: I wrote the plugin.

Enjoy!

Comment: This is really promising, and is not OS-dependent as is the accepted answer!One problem is that if there are non-jar dependencies, the plugin will just fail to launch on invalid classpath argument. Is there a way to do the equivalent of -DincludeTypes=jar as in the other answer? I can't use this plugin in a project that has a .nar dependency.

Comment: Tried this with spring-based project, but it does not see spring. I ran it where pom.xml was. Could not import anything from org.springframework. ... ; Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @jpoth, thanks for writing the plugin.

Answer (score 3):

See [In Maven, how to output the classpath being used?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16655010/1744774).

According to:

```
jshell --help
```

run JShell with:

```
jshell --class-path <path>
```

Comment: This gives you the dependency classes but not the project classes. Is there a straightforward way to include those as well, so you can use a REPL over your entire project?

Comment: Could you update this with a working sample or a detailed explanation of how does this work actually for you?

Answer (score 2):

Because of [JDK bug 8177650](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8177650), the solutions here using the `--class-path` option or launching from maven will break package autocompletion. Here is a bash one-liner that works with package autocompletion:

```
CLASSPATH=`mvn dependency:build-classpath -DincludeTypes=jar -Dmdep.outputFile=/dev/stderr 2>&1 >/dev/null`:target/classes jshell
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Groovy shell (`groovysh`) instead and do `groovy.grape.Grape.grab([group:"<maven group>", artifact:"<maven artifact ID>", version:"<version>"])` - this will give you REPL with necessary Maven dependencies in classpath.

Not sure if jshell has any advantages over Groovy shell that are worth the pain with Maven dependencies.