# JShell console in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, jshell

[IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1 has a built-in JShell](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2017/09/java-9-and-intellij-idea/), which [imports all the project's libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48143960/how-to-import-a-custom-class-in-intellij-jshell-console?rq=1) etc.

Is it possible to use this in Android Studio? (It is not in the `Tools` menu, as said in the blog post).

---

UPDATE: Android still does not support Java 8 completely, JShell is Java 9. It might still be possible to use the [gradle jshell plugin](https://github.com/bitterfox/jshell-gradle-plugin), or use the [Kotlin REPL](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/command-line.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can also use my project [jshell-plugin](https://github.com/mrsarm/jshell-plugin) that is a fork of the *gradle jshell plugin* you mentioned, but with [improved features](https://github.com/mrsarm/jshell-plugin#about).

Also as you mentioned, you need JDK 9+ to run it, but if it is not your default JDK and you don't want to change that configuration from your local environment, here is a [trick](https://github.com/mrsarm/jshell-plugin#i-have-a-jdk-9-installation-but-my-default-jdk-is-the-jdk-8-or-below):

```
$ export JAVA_HOME="/path/to/jdk9+"
$ gradle --console plain jshell
```

The `export` of the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable will have effect only in the active console you have opened.