# I have stored all the jar file into specific folder. How to configure specific folder to Jshell classpath ?

Tags: java, java-9, jshell

I have stored all the jar file into specific folder and I have added specific folder to Jshell classpath. I am unable to import packages in `jshell` after adding classpath.

It is working fine If I have mentioned all the jar file name in classpath. I don't want to mentioned all the Jar file name in classpath because I have to add more than thousand number of jar files into classpath.

How to configure specific folder to Jshell classpath ?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `*` [wildcard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1237093/how-to-use-a-wildcard-in-the-classpath-to-add-multiple-jars)?

Comment: You can either use `:` separated, complete list of `jar`s or the plugin mentioned in the answers of the duplicate question link. I can confirm both the ways just work fine.

Answer (score 4):

Declare the path of classpath in jshell.

```
jshell> /env -class-path path_of_dependecies
```

If classpath is current working folder

```
jshell> /env -class-path .
```

When you call specific class or call static method from dependencies, you must use command import

```
jshell> import com.foo_company.*
```

See authoritative tutorial http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~rfield/tutorial/JShellTutorial.html#setting-a-classpath